# How to add column based on another column value in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How do I take data frame, like the following:

```
      col1    col2
row0   abc      3
row1   bcd     2.4
```

And produce a dataframe with new column which value based on col2, is number has dot in it or not, like the following:

```
      col1    col2    col3
row0   abc      3     No dot
row1   bcd     2.4    Has dot
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), because `.` is special regex character escape it by `\`:

```
df['col3'] = np.where(df['col2'].astype(str).str.contains('\.'), 'Has dot', 'No dot')
```

Or use `regex=False` parameter:

```
df['col3'] = np.where(df['col2'].astype(str).str.contains('.', regex=False), 
                      'Has dot', 'No dot')
```

---

```
print (df)

     col1 col2     col3
row0  abc    3   No dot
row1  bcd  2.4  Has dot
```

Answer (score 4):

The following should work:

```
df['col3']=df['col2'].apply(lambda x: 'No dot' if int(x)==x else 'Has dot')
```